# TWTweetComposeViewController with canSendTweet

Tags: ios, twitter, ios5

I read Apple's literature on TWTweetComposeviewController.  It said "use the canSendTweet class method to check if Twitter is setup and reachable before presenting this view to the user. "  I interpreted that "reachable" to mean canSendTweet will check to see if Twitter can be reached ....  When I tested this, only the former is working as stated.  But not the latter.  It will detect if user has not entered info in Settings.  But it could not detect if there is no network.

Any comments?

Answer (score 0):

The network check is a separate thing. See http://www.jameskelso.com/post/10251501993/getting-network-change-notifications-in-ios-using.